# Accessing Individual elements of cv::Mat_16UC1

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv

I have a cv::Mat object of type 16UC1 which is basically containing the depth values from a kinect device, I tried several methods like using

```
    cout << depthMat.at<uchar>(0,0) << endl;
    cout << depthMat.at<char>(0,0) << endl;
    cout << depthMat.at<double>(0,0) << endl;
```

etc. but all of them gives ambiguous results. Any idea how can i access these 16-bit values in eclipse c++/opencv in linux enviroment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the code to

```
cout << depthMat.at<unsigned short>(0,0) << endl;
```